# letterspacing italic small caps automatically

Tags: fontspec, small-caps, microtype, letterspacing

The `MinionPro-It.otf` file I am using contains italic small caps, confirmed with `otfinfo -f MinionPro-It.otf` and `cfftot1 MinionPro-It.otf | t1testpage | epstopdf --filter > MinionPro-It.pdf`.

The following code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}]{Minion Pro}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\SetTracking[no ligatures]{encoding = *, shape = sc*}{250}
\newcommand*\qbf{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\begin{document}
\qbf

\textit{\qbf}

\textbf{\qbf}

\textbf{\textit{\qbf}}

\textsc{\qbf}

\textsc{\textbf{\qbf}}

\textsc{\textit{\qbf}}

\textls[250]{\textsc{\textit{\qbf}}}
\end{document}
```

produces
[image]
using `luatex 0.76` on a recenty updated TeXLive 2013.

The medium and bold small caps are letter spaced automatically, however the italic small caps in the second to last line are not. It is possible to explicitly specify letter spacing as seen in the last line. But I have found no way to enable automatic letter spacing of italic small caps.

Section 15.8.4 on page 167 of the `microtype` manual contains the code for setting the protrusion settings for the Minion italic small caps, hinting that the shape may be named `scit` or `si`. Unfortunately changing the `\SetTracking` parameters makes no difference. Any idea why it works for `sc + bf` but not for `sc + it`?

Comment: Have you tried using the package for `MinionPro`? There is a file `MinionPro-FontDef.sty` which looks as if it does a lot of the kind of set up you might need here. (Obviously, I'm not sure if it would actually solve this particular problem.) Because the shapes you are talking about are probably not going to be set up by default, since they are not default shapes at all.

Comment: @cfr I haven’t checked, but isn’t the package for the PostScript version of the font only?

Comment: Probably you're right. I didn't investigate terribly closely. Possibly the names of packages are misleading (I saw it used `otfontdef`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, `microtype` will enable tracking for the fonts defined in the `smallcaps` set (see `microtype.cfg`), which includes all `sc` shape fonts, but not `si`, that is italic smallcaps. You should get what you want if you add the following to the preamble:

```
\DeclareMicrotypeSet*{smallcapsi}
   { encoding = {OT1,T1,T2A,LY1,OT4,QX,T5,TS1,EU1,EU2},
     shape    = {sc*,si,scit}
   }
```

Why is `si` not included in the `smallcaps` set? Well, it probably will be in the next version, but to give some explanation let me say that the `si` shape is a rather recent, unofficial addition to LaTeX's font selection scheme. The `NFSS` ("new" font selection scheme) puts small caps and italics on the same font axis, making it mutually exclusive, while bold is a different axis, so that it can be combined with small caps (or italics, for that matter). The `fontspec` package (and others) remedy this design flaw by introducing the `si` shape (the `slantsc` package calls it `scit`), which allows selecting italic smallcaps.

Comment: Does `sc*` refer to any shape that *starts* with `sc`? We could also `\renewcommand\sidefault{scit}`. (I'd possibly be okay with changing this in fontspec if it helped in general.)

Comment: @WillRobertson `sc*` just translates into `\scdefault` here. As for `si` vs. `scit` I'd say the former is more common (eg. `nfssext`), and I don't see any advantage in changing it. I'll add both to `microtype.cfg` anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, @Robert beat me to it by a few seconds.

Here is the version I had come up with in the mean time. Note, even if you use
@Robert's answer, you still also need to modify your `\SetTracking` line
as I've shown here to disable ligatures for shape `si`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}]{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DeclareMicrotypeSet{mysmallcaps}
   { encoding = {OT1,T1,T2A,LY1,OT4,QX,T5,TS1,EU1,EU2},
     shape    = {sc*,si}
   }
\microtypesetup{tracking=mysmallcaps}
\SetTracking[no ligatures]{encoding = *, shape = {sc*,si}}{250}
\newcommand*\qbf{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\begin{document}
\qbf

\textit{\qbf}

\textbf{\qbf}

\textbf{\textit{\qbf}}

\textsc{\qbf}

\textsc{\textbf{\qbf}}

\textsc{\textit{\qbf}}

\textls[250]{\textsc{\textit{\qbf}}}
\end{document}
```

to get this:

[image]