# Tracking in full caps and italicized small caps

Tags: fonts, microtype

The [microtype](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package includes a tracking option, in which the space between letters is increased. This should normally be done for sequences of both full caps and small caps, see e.g. [Bringhurst's style book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881792128).

The tracking set by `microtype`, however, appears only in upright small caps, not for italicized small caps, and not for full caps at all. I find this somewhat odd, and it honestly looks inappropriate in a document that uses all of them. Is there a way to circumvent this problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tracking = true]{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
ABCD \textsc{abcd} \textit{ABCD \textsc{abcd}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157424/7674

Comment: @Robert Does that solution extend beyond ``fontspec`` and ``luatex``?

Comment: Yes, it's the same for good old `pdftex`, only that you need to specify the right encodings (ie. those from the default set `smallcaps` from `microtype.cfg`). [I've edited the answer accordingly.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhat embarrassing, but I found the answer just minutes later. I'll post it here rather than deleting my question, in case future users have the same question.

Tracking can be set manually on an ad-hoc basis with the `\textls[amount]{text}` command (`textls` = text letterspace). Since the default amount of letterspacing is 100 (= 100/1000 em), I'm setting it to `100` below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tracking = true]{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\textls[100]{ABCD} \textsc{abcd} \textls[100]{\textit{ABCD \textsc{abcd}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For `pdflatex` you can also use package `soul`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\so{ABCD} \textsc{abcd} \so{\textit{ABCD \textsc{abcd}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Load the package 'soulutf8' if you need better support for UTF8.