# Set tracking amount with microtype

Tags: fonts, microtype

The question is this: How can I globally set the amount of tracking to be executed with [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype)'s `\textls` command?

More details:

The `microtype` package gives the option of setting the space between letters. This is called `letterspacing` or `tracking`. `microtype` will do this automatically only for upright small capitals, not for full capitals or italicized small capitals. This can, however, be set manually with the `\textls` command, see [Tracking in full caps and italicized small caps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183602/tracking-in-full-caps-and-italicized-small-caps) for details.

To avoid having to specify the amount of tracking every time the `\textls` command is used, as shown in the linked question above, I'd like to set it globally with `\SetTracking`. Cf. the `microtype` manual under `5.3`:

> The \SetTracking command allows specifying the tracking amount for
>   different fonts or font sets. It will also be evaluated by the \textls
>   command [...].

This command has the structure `\SetTracking[<options>]{<set of fonts>}{<tracking amount>}`, see `5.3`. The `<set of fonts>` is explained in the manual under `4`, where it says:

> If an attribute list is empty or missing [...] it does not constitute
>   a restriction. In other words, this is equivalent to specifying all
>   possible values for that attribute.

Given this, it should be possible to use `\SetTracking{}{<tracking amount>}` to set the amount of tracking used when `\textls` is called.

For some reason, however, this doesn't work. In the MWE below, the command `\SetTracking{}{500}` seems to be ignored. Only the setting `letterspace = 50` as `microtype` option seems to be evaluated.

Question: How can I globally set the amount of tracking to be executed with `\textls`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tracking = true, letterspace = 50]{microtype}
    \SetTracking{}{500}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\textls{ABCD} \textsc{abcd} \textls[500]{\textit{ABCD \textsc{abcd}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Tracking]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tracking = true, letterspace = 50]{microtype}
    \SetTracking{encoding=*}{500}
    \SetTracking{encoding=*, shape=sc}{50}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\textls{ABCD} \textsc{abcd} \textls[500]{\textit{ABCD \textsc{abcd}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see that the manual uses ``encoding=*`` as well (but I didn't see an explanation for it), but it puzzles me why this is necessary. When compiling with ``luatex``, for example, ``encoding`` isn't a relevant feature anyway.

Comment: @Sverre Yes. I couldn't find an explanation in the manual either. I posted an answer anyway just because you'd asked how to do it and not why! But it would be good to have an explanation. I didn't try with `luatex` but that does seem odd...

Comment: Also, I see in your example that ``\SetTracking{encoding=*}{500}`` simply overrides ``letterspace = 50``. If not then ``\textsc{abcd}`` should have come out with a letterspace of ``50/1000em``. So this seems to be equivalent to just setting ``letterspace = 500``.

Comment: @Sverre See update to answer. I assume it changes the spacing for `\textsc` since the change affects `\textls` *as well as* other things. But the documentation is not very clear about these matters.

Comment: Right, it seems like ``\SetTracking`` is simply a more detailed version of the ``tracking`` and ``letterspace`` options that lets you fine-tune the tracking according to various font features. If there's a conflict between ``\SetTracking`` and the ``microtype`` options, then the former takes precedence. The ``\textls`` command is affected by whichever setting has taken precedence. As you say, the manual doesn't spell this out very clearly.

Comment: @Sverre I am not certain but I think there's some sort of 'default set' at work such that by default, `\SetTracking` applies to whatever is in that default set. Although the docs talk about adding extra spacing *uniformly* to all letters/characters in a font, what seems to happen is that if nothing is specified, a default grouping is invoked. (At least if `encoding=*` is specified and nothing else.) So it will affect small-caps but not, say, regular upright. But I'm not really very sure how all of this fits together. Is it just what is specified first? Or do some have priority regardless?