# Tracking amount in Microtype for textsc won't change

Tags: bibliographies, microtype

The bibliography style I am using (`abbrvdin`) uses for the author names all capital letters (like `\textsc{}`). When tracking in microtype is enabled it adds space between all those letters which doesn't look very good. I searched around and found one solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183693/set-tracking-amount-with-microtype).

```
\SetTracking{encoding=*, shape=sc}{50}
```

This unfortunatly does not work for me. The space between letters stays the same. What am I doing wrong?

Little more information, I am using: scrreprt, font libertine, bibstyle addrvdin and ngerman babel enabled.

Edit: 
I switched from libertine back to default font but the spacing didn't change to
the value I have provided by `SetTracking`.

Edit 2: 
I have found a way around that issue

```
\microtypesetup{tracking=false}
\bibliography{lit}
\microtypesetup{tracking=true}
```

But this would also diable tracking in bib in non small capitals. 
So I would rather have a better solution.

**EDIT:**
I am very sorry that it took me so long to add an example. But here it finally is:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    paper=a4,
    titlepage=true,
    twoside=true,
    numbers=noenddot,
    parskip=half,
    headings=small,
    draft
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
    activate={true,nocompatibility},
    final,
    tracking=true,
    kerning=true,
    factor=1100,
    stretch=10,
    shrink=10
]{microtype}
\SetTracking{encoding=*, shape=sc}{200}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine,cmintegrals,cmbraces,vvarbb]{newtxmath}

\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvdin}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Something}
    Blah\dots\cite{carrier,kobayashi}

    \bibliography{literatur}
\end{document}

%%% CONTENT OF BBL FILE %%%
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

% this bibliography is generated by abbrvdin.bst [8.2] from 2005-12-21

\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[1]{carrier}
\textsc{Carrier}, B. :
\newblock \emph{File System Forensic Analysis}.
\newblock Addison Wesley Professional, 2005

\bibitem[2]{kobayashi}
\textsc{Kobayashi}, Y.  ; \textsc{Sommer}, C. :
\newblock On shortes disjoint paths in planar graphs.
\newblock {In: }\emph{Discrete Optimization}  (2010), Nr. 7, S. 234--245

\end{thebibliography}
```

As said in the initial question the `SetTracking` command does not solve the issue. I have to disable tracking completly to set it correct. Or else it looks like this:
[image: This is what it looks like]

And this is what I think it should like when done right:

[image]
**EDIT 2:**

Well I fixed the problem. Instead of

```
\SetTracking{encoding={*}, shape=sc}{40}
```

I used

```
\SetTracking{encoding={T1}, shape=sc}{40}
```

and it worked.

But, as in the comments pointed out, only small caps are kerned, everything else not.

Comment: @ap0, might be an idea if you also provide a bibliography. Or at least just the contents of this two item `.bbl` file (just past it in to the example, BibTeX does not seem relevant to this issue).

Comment: Your second screenshot doesn't seem to feature *any* tracking (aka letter-spacing) for words set in small-caps. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Mico this is correct. the second image has tracking set to false for the complete document.

Comment: If you want zero tracking, don't set the option "tracking" to "true" when loading the `microtype` package.

Comment: I think @ap0 want tracking in the document, but not in the bibliography.

Comment: @Mico, delif is right. I want tracking but not within `\textsc` because (see image) it looks bad.

Comment: Where else is there any tracking? I do not see anything else but textsc

Comment: @daleif, hmm, you seem to be right. I turned it on globaly and for larger text there were zero changes to it. I guess I am doing something else wrong. But you are right, only textsc is tracked (?)

Comment: To me, the correct syntax is `\SetTracking{encoding={*}, shape=sc}{40}` (i.e. with brackets). But it did not tested it.

Comment: @Clément, it doesn't change the tracking amount. But thank you.

Comment: @daleif, I fixed the problem. See my edit! But as you pointed out, only textsc is kerned, everything else not. Should I open new Question for this?

Comment: Then my question is, what exactly is it you want to be tracked/kerned?

Comment: @daleif, maybe I understand the concept of tracking wrong. I assumed that with tracking enabled microtype will take care of all text within a document automatically to make is visually more pleasing. What it exactly does, I cannot tell you.

Comment: @ap0 well it deals with letterspacing. Normal text is generally not letterspaced as it may look odd. In many cases letterspacing capitals or small caps will lead to something more visually pleasing. So the question is whether you have other constructions in your document that would benefit from tracking/letterspacing. See the microtype manual

Comment: @daleif, thank you for the small explanation. If tracking is not used in normal text, then I think I expected something wrong here. Except small caps in the bibliography and source code in listings I don't think there is nothing else needed for tracking. And listings look fine to me.

Comment: Tracking i code listings? Doesn't the listings package handle that with one of its options.

Comment: @daleif, I guess. But since listings look fine to me I wasn't planing to change it anyway.

Comment: @Mico, what was asked is to change tracking for small caps and I wrote the solution that I have found in my question at the very bottom.

Comment: @Mico, If I use: `\SetTracking{endocing={*},shapce=sc{x}`: no matter which value I use for `x` the spacing between small caps is not changed. Even for `x=400`. But if I change it to `encoding={T1} I can see an emediat change in spacing depending on the `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asterisk in

```
\SetTracking{encoding=*, shape=sc}{50}
```

is a placeholder that stands for "default". While for the `\Declare...` commands the translation of this placeholder takes place at the end of the preamble, for the `\Set...` commands, it takes places immediately. In your example, this results in the asterisk being translated to `OT1`, because `inputenc` -- which changes the default encoding to `T1` -- is loaded two lines later.

Therefore, to have the asterisk expand to the default encoding that is actually used in the document, you should load `inputenc` before `microtype`.